# Wierd window look for system apps

Tags: unity, 13.10, system-settings

I installed some special programs a time ago and added several extra repositories. After trying those apps, I uninstalled them and the according repos.

For a several amount of time, I have wierd looking system windows (system settings e.g.). How can I restore the default system apps?

[image]

[image]

Udate:
This is not related to the selected theme. Those themes worked well before, I think, the whole system settings app changed, but I'm not quite sure. If you can compare your for e.g. audio settings tool with mine, you will see a difference.

Comment: What was the program you used to change settings with? You can also try to set the Ambiance theme back with Systemsettings > Appearance.

Comment: I updated my question, that this is not a theme issue.

Comment: Ok, but what was the program?

Comment: I have no clue, which installtion has overwritten my system apps. Is there any possibility to revert the system-settings application?

Comment: do you remember any theme editing application? Obviously the windowbackroundcolour is pimped :) Is that the only change you notice?

Comment: another question: is there a folder called ".themes" in `~/` or in `~/.local/share/`? (invisible by default, click ctrl-h to see)

Comment: I'm using the gnome-tweak-tool, but it has never changed the windows like this. I also have no theme folder in both of your mentioned folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of related bugs that describe this behaviour. See e.g. [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-default-settings/+bug/1167079). As far as I can tell, it is a bug that comes and goes. You may try to disable scroll overlay bars as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1102096).

Comment: _sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:amd64 overlay-scrollbar-gtk3:amd64_

Solved the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think installing "gnome-tweak-tool" then using that to change the theme to "Ambience" will fix this.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Run gnome tweak tool from terminal by issuying the command: gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: This is not related to the selected theme. Those themes worked well before, I think, the whole system settings app changed maybe...