# How to fix colours in the Software Centre?

Tags: software-center

The Software Centre on Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04 and 15.04 is showing up a colour scheme that renders the text hardly readable:

[image]

Apparently, it is mixing colours from the desktop theme with its own theme and the end result is somewhat of a blur. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: could it be connected to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/439892/wierd-window-look-for-system-apps#comment574378_439892 ?

Comment: No, I only have this issue with the Software Centre, all system windows and applications are rendered fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open up a terminal and type the following command:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
   ```
2. The first two lines should look like this:

   ```css
   @define-color light-aubergine #DED7DB;
   @define-color super-light-aubergine #F4F1F3;
   ```

   Copy and paste those two lines right below then comment out the originals, by enclosing them between `/*` and `*/`. Change the two HTML color codes (`#DED7DB` and `#F4F1F3`) to your preferred dark colors so that dark text will show up.
3. Save and close Gedit. Launch Ubuntu Software Center to check out the results.

   As an example, the first lines of css file now look like this:

   ```css
   @define-color light-aubergine #CD4634;
   @define-color super-light-aubergine #CD4635;
   ```

This colour scheme is Numix orange.

Comment: This solution is also viable on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: It's the `super-light-aubergine` that mattered most, in my experience. I used `@define-color super-light-aubergine dimgrey;` for a colour more consistent with dark themes.